# Is Captain America at peak human potential mentally?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america

Did the supersoldier serum modify his mental capabilities?

Any canon universe is acceptable.

Comment: He doesn’t seem unusually smart...

Comment: Based on what is called "supersoldier" serum. I'm assuming, No.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it did. While he was never shown to have intelligence like Reed Richards or Hank McCoy, he did possess a different type of intelligence. The aforementioned characters were experts in Science and thus most of their knowledge was knowledge that could be learned. The super soldier serum didn't feed Captain America with facts or information. It sharpened his mental *capabilities*. This is **directly stated** here:[image]***"My newly augmented brain began to soak in knowledge..."***

His **memory power** is shown here:
[image]
***"My mind was enhanced to the point that I could remember any military tactic and apply it to any situation"***

His **quickness in learning/thinking** is shown here:
[image]

***"...already he adapts--mastering the form more completely than many who've trained for decades!"***

[image]

***"Commander Rogers is a Super-Soldier who can master any weapon in seconds."***

[image]

***"I realized I've exposed my back----and did exactly what he wanted me to do."***

Captain America has an amazing body and an amazing mind which is what makes him who he is. While his intelligence is not shown as much as his physical abilities, we can never downplay his phenomenal mental acuity.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

### Probably

In Captain America #109 (1969), the physician who creates the super-serum seems to believe it will give him perfect mental powers:

[image]

Apparently, once he has taken the serum, Steve Rogers embodies the ideal of "a sound mind in a sound body." **This would seem to indicate that the serum enhanced his mental powers as well.**

As indicated in the comic page [found here](http://comicvine.gamespot.com/captain-america/4005-1442/forums/cap-s-brain-1488520/), it would seem he is at least mentally enhanced: 
[image]

The doctor says that Steve is now "the first of a corps of super-soldiers whose **mental** and physical ability will make them a terror to spies and saboteurs."

On the other hand, despite the ample evidence that the serum has often been conceived as giving Captain America mental perfection as well as physical, he doesn't seem to display this in many areas. He is often said to possess great tactical genius, and his reaction speed has certainly been enhanced. (how else could block bullets so effectively?) He also seems to be excellent at calculating trajectories, judging by how he bounces his shield off of things.

He never seems to display the analytic genius of a Stark or Richards, though. Perhaps this is merely due to disinclination, since many origin stories (as mentioned above), he apparently has superhuman mental abilities.

Comment: Perhaps it refers to mental stability? I mean, he's a soldier for a century, perhaps it prevents him from developing PTSD?

Comment: @Broklynite - Maybe!

Comment: There's a comic that references the serum as raising his mental capabilities.. it was an old old comic that was explaining how he's a "master of vector mechanics, which allows him to ricochet his shield and catch it perfectly" 

Sorry I can't cite!

Comment: I guess Captain America is an example of how learning projectile motion and trigonometry in school can help you in life...